# Why stream() doesn't work from just declared Array

Tags: java, arrays, java-stream

It's probably sth simple, but I can't find answers why I can't start stream straight after creating List using Arrays.asList. 'list' is working fine, but 'list2' doesn't, no help from IntelliJ

```
 List<Book> list = Arrays.asList(lalka,dziady,chlopi,jutrzenka);

    list.stream()
            .map((Book var)-> var.getAuthor().getName())
            .forEach(var-> System.out.println(var));

    List<Book> list2 = Arrays.asList(lalka, dziady).stream()
            .map((Book var) -> var.getAuthor().getName())
            .forEach(var-> System.out.println(var));
```

Comment: "doesn't" is not an error. What happens? What kind of error do you get?

Comment: You're trying to assign the result of `forEach` to a variable. But `forEach` does not return anything.

Comment: Which part of documentation or specification makes you think that `forEach()` should return `List<Book>`?

Comment: *FYI:* `Arrays.asList(lalka, dziady).stream()` is better written as `Stream.of(lalka, dziady)`

Answer (score 1):

Your stream pipeline doesn't return anything (the terminal operation `forEach` has a `void` return type) so you can't assign it to a `List` variable.

You can write:

```
Arrays.asList(lalka, dziady)
      .stream()
      .map((Book var) -> var.getAuthor().getName())
      .forEach(var-> System.out.println(var));
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to assign result of `.forEach` to a `List<Book> list2` variable.
`.forEach(...)` is of type `void`.
Remove this unnecessary assignment.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the assignment to List list2.
You'll probably be getting an error that you cannot convert void to list
as **.forEach()** does not return anything.

Remove the assignment to list2 and this compiles and runs just fine.